# Php random order for imported .php pages [solved]

Tags: php, random

**Version with 1 result**

```
<?php
srand();
$files = array("folder/content1.php", "folder/content2.php", "folder/content3.php", "folder/content4.php", "folder/content5.php", "folder/content6.php");
$rand = array_rand($files);
include ($files[$rand]);
?>
```

**Version with 5 results (provided by Code Spirit)**

```
<?php
$files = array("folder/content1.php", "folder/content2.php", "folder/content3.php", "folder/content4.php", "folder/content5.php", "folder/content6.php");
foreach (array_rand($files, 5) as $file) {
  include($files[$file]);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a loop.

```
foreach (array_rand($files, 3) as $file) {
  include($files[$file]);
}
```